# migartion sharepoint web application sharepoint 2013 to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

actually i tried to migrate lists and document libraries from one site to another site in sharepoint 2013 and migrate sites also from 2010 to sharepoint 2013. But,I want to migrate web application from sharepoint 2013 to sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

We are limited to creating Site collections only in SharePoint online. You cannot create/migrate the complete web application to SharePoint online in one go. You would have to migrate either a complete site collection or site level.

I have experience migrating with [SharePoint migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool) from Microsoft (which is free software) and it worked well.

However, i would suggest to migrate individual site level as it would be easy to manage. I have tried migrating a site collection which failed after 40% and it was difficult to debug where the error was. I later figured it was the nintex form on a document library that was a culprit.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You may use below methods to create apps

- Using SharePoint Apps ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins )
- Use the latest SPFx framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) to create apps.